# SignalR: Sending message back only to AJAX caller from the code behind page (outside of Hub/PersistentConnection)

Tags: asp.net, ajax, signalr

I'm struggling with this a bit. What I'm trying to achieve is to send message back to the Ajax caller (aspx page) from the server (aspx page's code behind) to update the progress of a time consuming task being done at the server.

I'm trying the following code from the code behind of the aspx page, but that doesn't seem to work!

```
_context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetConnectionContext<MessengerEndpoint>();
_context.Connection.Send(((Connection)_context.Connection).Identity, "hey");
```

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Any takers? @dfowler/@N.TaylorMullen?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can try (only try):

```
Context.Connection.Broadcast ( "hey");
```

if it will work (and I think it will work(, the problem is the `Identity`, so you nedd to open a connection and save the connection ID on server or in the client for later use.

Comment: .Broadcast sends to all connections except the caller! Its the same thing with 
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MessageHub>();
context.Clients.All.postMessage("hey");

which is very frustrating! The system should just broadcast to everyone when it says 'broadcast'/'All' and let developers handle the exclusions!

Comment: you are right, but you need to remember that the code behind / Controller is not the connection. 
do you have the connectionID from SignalR?

Comment: Well it seems like my Ajax call got invoked before the connection had a chance to setup. Hence it was invoking to all other clients than to the one I was on. Btw, Im on IE8. So now that it broadcasts to all, whats next? I was trying to somehow pass the hub id from server (outside of hub) back to the client so that I could check whether the hub id matches and only then prompt the notification. But I could not find any way to access Hub id. IHubContext doesnt expose that value as opposed to Hub.Context which does (ConnectionId)! Im not sure why these two inherit from two different interfaces!